# Unramified extension of Dedekind domains implies etale covering

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, field-theory

I'm using the following (nonstandard?) definition of an etale ring homomorphism: $f: A \rightarrow B$ is etale if $B$ is finite, projective, and separable as an $A$-module.  Here separable is defined as saying that the trace map $B \rightarrow A$ is nondegenerate, as in [these](https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masmat/files/notes/etalenotes.pdf) notes that I'm reading.  The picture below is from the same set of notes (pg. 23).

[image]

$B$ is a finitely generated module over $A$ (maybe we need $L/K$ separable for this, not sure), and since $A_{\mathfrak p}$ is a PID, $B$ is projective as an $A$-module.  I'm trying to see why $B/A$ being unramified implies nondegeneracy of the trace, and moreover how a prime of $A$ being ramified in $B$ would prevent this from happening.

Comment: Assuming $L/K$ separable, is this not the standard criterion for primes of $K$ ramifying in $L$ ? Namely, primes dividing the discriminant (which is the determinant of the traces of $e_i e_j$, $e_i$ basis for $B$, at least locally)?

Comment: BTW, 'unimodular' is probably more appropriate than the 'nondegenerate' above: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_form#unimodular (the notions differing if one is not talking about vector spaces)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathfrak d$ be the different of $L/K$ (assumed finite and separable), which controls ramification.

The trace pairing $\mathfrak d^{-1} \times B \rightarrow A$ induces $\mathfrak d^{-1} \cong B^{\vee} = \text{Hom}_A(B,A)$, and no fractional ideal $I \subsetneq \mathfrak d^{-1}$ satisfies $I \cong B^{\vee}$ via the trace pairing.

Comment: How do you know that $\mathfrak d^{-1} \rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}_A(B,A)$ is surjective?

Comment: Since $L/K$ is separable, the trace induces $L \cong \text{Hom}_K(L,K)$; every $f:B \rightarrow A$ extends to $\tilde f: L \rightarrow K$.