# An algebraic proof that every finite extension of $\mathbb Q$ is ramified?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

A basic result in algebraic number theory is that every proper finite extension of $\mathbb Q$ is ramified over $\mathbb Q$.  This is proved by considering Minkowski's lower bound on the discriminant.

I read somewhere that there is no known proof of this result which is purely algebraic.  However, can we argue like this?

Let $A$ be a ring, and let $B$ be an algebra over $A$ which is finite and projective as an $A$-module.  Then the trace map $\operatorname{Tr}: B \rightarrow A$ can be defined.  We say that $B$ is *separable* over $A$ if $b \mapsto \phi_b, \phi_b(b') = \operatorname{Tr}(bb')$ defines an isomorphism of $A$-modules $B \rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}_A(B,A)$.  Let's say that $B$ is *etale* over $A$ if it is finite, projective, and separable over $A$.

Then the result that every proper finite extension of $\mathbb Q$ is ramified follows from these two results:

(i): Let $A$ be a Dedekind domain with quotient field $K$, and let $B$ be the integral closure of $A$ in a finite separable extension $L$ of $K$.  If no prime of $A$ ramifies in $B$, then $B$ is etale as an $A$-algebra.

(ii): Every etale ring extension of $\mathbb Z$ is of the form $\mathbb Z^n$.

As far as I can tell, these two results are not hard.  The first follows from the answer to my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2751931/unramified-extension-of-dedekind-domains-implies-etale-covering/2859528#2859528), and I'm currently working out the second.

Does this argument give a simple proof for why there are no unramified extensions of $\mathbb Q$?  It seems a little too easy.

Comment: Please call back when you have a solution to (ii).

Comment: Fair enough, I should make sure there is no circular reasoning

Comment: As the analogue of (ii) must fail for general Dedekind domains, its proof cannot be too easy....

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't seem to be so easy.  Any idea how to prove?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown is right that this SHOULDN'T have a 'purely algebraic' solution. Think about $\mathbb{Z}$ as the analogue of $\mathbb{A}^1_k$ where $k$ is algebraically closed of characteristic $0$. How do you prove that $\pi_1(\mathbb{A}^1_k)=0$? You essentially do it by studying the finite covers of the compactification $\mathbb{P}^1_k$. Similarly, to show that $\pi_1(\text{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}))=0$ you should probably study the finite covers of the compactification of $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$. What does this mean though? Well, considering that the points of the smooth projective

Comment: curve associated to a function field $K/k$ correspond to valuations on $K$ (trivial on  $k$) one might imagine that the compactification of $\mathbb{Z}$ should have points corresponding to the valuations on $\mathbb{Q}$. These are $v_p$ AND the infinite place $v_\infty$. So to compactify you should study not just $\mathbb{Z}$ but also the 'point' $v_\infty$. Studying this infinite place is, as Arakaelov geometry has done for years, been of an inherently analytic nature. So, you really can't hope to escape the analysis. It's not a feature of the proof, it's a feature of the result.